# Having trouble chaining element calls in protractor

Tags: protractor

I know I saw the answer here before. I even used it to successfully build a chain earlier. However, that code is gone, my new code is failing for some reason, and, for the life of me, I cannot find the question on here that gave me the answer, so I'm left with no choice but to ask again.

I have a parent div, with several children divs. I need to pick out the 7th div and check its content against a previously constructed string.

I have the following line:

```
expect(element(by.css('.textLayer')).element.all(by.tagName('div')).get(6).getText()).toContain(expectedString);
```

but I'm getting an error:

```
Failed: element(...).element.all is not a function
```

I'm not sure what I'm missing.

Please feel free to even point me to the right answer that I know is on here, but somehow, my GoogleFu is failing to locate.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should change to

```
element(by.css('.textLayer')).all(by.tagName('div'))
```

Comment: Thanks! I knew I was missing something obvious! As soon as it lets me, I'll mark as the answer.

Comment: Sadly, the line of code isn't working since that final page isn't an Angular page. Thoughts on how to modify that line?

Comment: The code line not use any stuff related to angular like `ng-xxx`, It just to find element from page, Please show more code lines before this line

Comment: Actually, I figured it out! Thanks!